# Using swap file instead of a partition

Tags: linux, ext4, swap, swap-file

I just wondered while using a swap file instead of an dedicated partition seems to only have advantages, isn't a swap file is slower due to the filesystem's overhead like e.g. ext4's journaling?

Comment: This question has an answer here : https://serverfault.com/a/25708/430340

Comment: I already read this one, but it doesn't answer the difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

A swap**file** in a partition with other files would have to go through the filesystem, and could get fragmented slowing it down, but I don't think it would be noticeably slower than a dedicated swap **partition**. The disk speed for reading & writing would be essentially the same.

If you're using any swap, it means you're running out of ram (or swap is too "swappy") and the speed difference from ram (1-10GB/sec?) to disk (20-500MB/sec?) is very noticeable. For a real noticeable speed difference, get more ram or use less of it so you don't need to swap.

ps. If you've got gigs of extra ram, a filesystem in ram, like `ramfs` or `tmpfs` is lightning quick (but uses ram).

pim's comment link is good, on serverfault: [swap partition vs file for performance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/25653/swap-partition-vs-file-for-performance)

Comment: Yeah it does what you say, but you can store the swapped data either in a dedicated swap partition or just in file on your root partition. And my question is whether storing it as a file on the root partition leads to lower performnce due to the overhead of the filesystem.

Comment: Ah, I see, I read it as a regular partition vs swap file, which didn't quite compute ;-) Editing...

Comment: Don't you think it could much slower? ext4 has to practically write twice on the drive for each write in a file, because of its journaling functionality.